# Looking for an alternative to Telerik's MVC controls

Tags: telerik, open-source, telerik-mvc

I have a long experience of using a whole host of different tools from Telerik and, I have to say, I love them.

But I need an alternative. Why? Well, I want to start an Open Source project. The project will have a number of elements including an MVC frontend. Sadly, Telerik's licencing specifically prohibits the use of their components in Open Source Projects.

I'm going to need a number of components but most notably a Grid. Can anyone suggest a *usable* and *worthwhile* component set that I would be able to use in an Open Source project.

Any suggestions accepted.

Comment: You can use my wrapper for the datatables.net plugin https://github.com/mcintyre321/mvc.jquery.datatables

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. **Jquery UI** (https://jqueryui.com/) is good but you should search for good components (thousands of ones can be found!). For example JqGrid for grid : http://jqgrid.com/ and . The main advantage is Jquery based if you are in love with Jquery. Also Visual Studio has it in its default project template.
2. **Sencha ExtJs** is great but a little different approach (it is completely JavaScript based and not JQuery based but it is a comprehnsive platform). Its control gallery is fantastic. specially for grid. check this : http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/
3. **Kendo UI** (latest telerik project) : I am not sure about **KendoUI** license but it think its JavaScript components are open source (although their MVC extensions are not free). check it at : http://www.kendoui.com

Comment: Mahmoud. Thanks for the pointers.